# how to assert a string with variable iD in postman

Tags: postman, postman-testcase

```
{
    "data": {
        "notifications": [
            {
                "deeplink": "/users/1628507341",
                "viewed": false
            }
        ]
    },
    "status": "success"
}
```

how do I write Postman tests to verify the deeplink results  like below.

I already know the deeplink ID, I want to combine with the string "users"

```
pm.test("notification deeplink is correct", function () {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
    pm.expect(jsonData.data.notifications[0].deeplink).to.eql("/users/" + {{deeplink}});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pm.variables.get("variable_name")` to get value from variable in Postman script

```
let deeplink = pm.variables.get("deeplink");

pm.test("notification deeplink is correct", function () {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
    pm.expect(jsonData.data.notifications[0].deeplink).to.eql("/users/" + deeplink);
});
```